# Show that $D \subset f(\overline{D})$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be non-constant and analytic in closure of unit disk $\overline{D}$ and assume that if $|z|=1$ then $|f(z)|=1$. Show that $D \subset f(\overline{D})$.

By maximum modulus principle we know that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ but that only tells us that $f(\overline{D}) \subset \overline{D}.$

Answer (score 1):

First, let us show that $f$ must have a zero in $D$. If not, $1/f$ satisfies the same assumptions as $f$, and the maximum principle forces $f$ to be constant.

Secondly, let $a\in D$ and define
$$ \phi_a(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}. $$
Then $\phi_a$ is a biholomorphism of $D$ to itself swapping $a$ and $0$. If $f$ avoids the point $a$, let
$$
g(z) = \phi_a(f(z)).
$$
Then $g$ avoids $0$, so must be constant by the first part, which in turn makes $f$ constant.